# More steps from person until the Death Note than a pen still works?

Tags: death-note

I am writing a DN fic (not sure if that'd be appropriate, but I can give you a name of link if you would like, and don't care about this particular spoiler) where as one of (probably) minor plot points, Light gets an idea to try more layered medium of writing names than a pen. Such as, a listening device, which transfers data over a network to a computer that uses some sort of typing device to enter data into the Death Note. Would this work identically to a pen, according to canon?
 Thanks.

Comment: Please try to answer your questions by research first and show some of your efforts. All canon rules are available online and e.g. "How to use it VII" specifies: "The instrument to write with can be anything, e.g. cosmetics, blood, etc. as long as it can write directly onto the note and remains as legible letters." **directly**. Next time pleas do basic research to avoid such easily answered questions.

Answer (score 1):

A computer can’t kill with the Death Note because it requires the writer to think about the victims face when writing their name.

“The human whose name is written in this note shall die.

This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name.”